# Toolbar title is being drawn behind status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I faced a problem with `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayot`. I have `windowTranslucentStatus = true` in my style resource, and `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in top layout (`CoordinatorLayout`) of an `Activity`. But there is a problem: when I scroll donw, `Toolbar` goes up(that's OK), and `Toolbar` title stays visible through `StatusBar`.

Start state
[image: Start state]

End state. Here you can see text below `StatusBar`
[image: End state]

Xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.wldev.lawbite.enquerie.ChooseRecepientActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:title="@string/activity_chose_recipient_title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/search_icon_cd"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:tint="@color/black" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/find_by_name_hint"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/gray_50_transparent"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:dataSource="@{recipients}"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### One more thing

If I wrap some layout around `CoordinatorLayout` all will be OK and `Toolbar` will hide properly.

Comment: Try to remove this :  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Comment: Or make sure the activity is not translucent

Comment: @BasuSingh removing `scrollFlags` removes scrolling of toolbar (I want it to hide). Activity have `windowTranslucentStatus` true in Theme and that's all.

Comment: Try putting WindowTranslucentStatue=false;

Comment: This will do. Since, WindowTranslucentStatue=true will make your app draw behind status bar.

Comment: @BasuSingh but i want my app to draw behing status bar. Drawer and so on must be drawn behind statusbar

Comment: Then add,  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your AppBarLayout

Comment: Is this solved?..I have same requirement

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AppBarLayout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true
```

And, it will work.